# in opencv cv::stereoRectify()，given a point p(x, y) from srcImage, how to get the p'(x', y') at newImage

Tags: c++, opencv

I use opencv for stereo correction.
The main code is as follows, the parameters of the camera are known:

```
cv::Size imageSize = left_SrcImage.size();
cv::Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
cv::Mat map1x, map1y, map2x, map2y;
cv::stereoRectify(cvK1, cvD1, cvK2, cvD2, imageSize, cvR, cvT, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
cv::Mat map1Left, map2Left, map1Right, map2Right;
cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(cvK1, cvD1, R1, P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1Left, map2Left);
cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(cvK2, cvD2, R2, P2, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1Right, map2Right);
cv::Mat rectifiedLeft, rectifiedRight;
cv::remap(left_SrcImage, rectifiedLeft, map1Left, map2Left, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
cv::remap(right_SrcImage, rectifiedRight, map1Right, map2Right, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
cv::imwrite("rectify_left.bmp", rectifiedLeft);
cv::imwrite("rectify_right.bmp", rectifiedRight);
```

These codes work fine, but my problem as follows:
If i know a point p'(x', y') in rectifiedLeft, It is easy to get the coordinates of the corresponding point of p' in the left_SrcImage p(x, y).

```
cv::Point2f SrcPoint;  // point p(x, y) in left_SrcImage
cv::Point2f NewPoint;  // A known point p'(x', y') in rectifiedLeft
SrcPoint.x = map1Left.at<cv::Vec2s>(NewPoint.y, NewPoint.x)[0];
SrcPoint.y = map1Left.at<cv::Vec2s>(NewPoint.y, NewPoint.x)[1];
```

BUT, if I known a point p(x, y) in left_SrcImage, How can I get the coordinates of the corresponding point p' in rectifiedLeft?
Point dst->src seems to be very easy, but how to src->dst?

I tried many ways, but no good solution.

Comment: `undistortPoints()`

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, this function can achieve coordinate conversion.